# Jumps in integrate()?

Tags: r, integral

I need to calculate a few integrals. I am aware that R is not the right software for doing this, but as I did everything else in R and the integrals were only one-dimensional, I thought it might be no problem.

Anyway, using the function `integrate()` from the stats package leads to a jump, when increasing the upper limit of the integral. Here is the plot:

[image: Plot using integrate()]

However, if I do by building the sum instead of the integral, or by using the function `adaptIntegrate()` from the `cubature` package, the result looks like this:

[image: Plot using adaptIntegrate()]

To be able to replicate this, here is the code. I know there is probably an easier example, but this is actually 1:1 the case I am facing. Using `integrate()`:

```
v_p = 11269
d_p = seq(0, v_p, 100)
tau = 0.35
interest = 0.05
time_t = 1
mu = 0
sigma_p = 0.1099313
nu_p = 0.0101552
ts = c()
bc = c()
for (i in 1:length(d_p)){
  ts  = c(ts,integrate(function(x) tau*(x-v_p-interest*d_p[i])*dlnorm(x, log(v_p)+(mu - 0.5 * sigma_p^2) * time_t, sigma_p*sqrt(time_t)), v_p+interest*d_p[i], 10000000)$value)
  bc = c(bc,integrate(function(y) nu_p * y * dlnorm(y, log(v_p)+(mu - 0.5 * sigma_p^2) * time_t, sigma_p*sqrt(time_t)), 0, d_p[i])$value)
}
shv = ts + bc
plot(d_p,shv, main = 290801)
abline(v = 9079, col="red")
```

Exactly the same code, just using adaptIntegrate():

```
v_p = 11269
d_p = seq(0, v_p, 100)
tau = 0.35
interest = 0.05
time_t = 1
mu = 0
sigma_p = 0.1099313
nu_p = 0.0101552
ts = c()
bc = c()
for (i in 1:length(d_p)){
  ts  = c(ts,adaptIntegrate(function(x) tau*(x-v_p-interest*d_p[i])*dlnorm(x, log(v_p)+(mu - 0.5 * sigma_p^2) * time_t, sigma_p*sqrt(time_t)), v_p+interest*d_p[i], 10000000)$integral)
  bc = c(bc,adaptIntegrate(function(y) nu_p * y * dlnorm(y, log(v_p)+(mu - 0.5 * sigma_p^2) * time_t, sigma_p*sqrt(time_t)), 0, d_p[i])$integral)
}
shv = ts + bc
plot(d_p,shv, main = 290801)
abline(v = 9079, col="red")
```

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: This is not a replicable example as you have not defined all your constants in the formulae - tau, interest, etc.

Comment: Also, it is a bad idea to use t as a variable name since it is the name of the transpose function. I tried your code with some made-up values for the parameters that you did not supply.  I got no jump in the results.

Comment: I am sorry. I added the missing variables. I changed t to time_t and still have the jump.

Comment: In the `ts` formula, I think you have a bracket or a comma in the wrong place, as there is a comma in the middle of your function(x).

Comment: Do you mean the ones belonging to dlnorm? I cannot find a wrong comma or bracket.. Anyway, the adaptIntegrate() code should be equal and does not have a jump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the second paragraph of the *Note* in `?integrate`:

> When integrating over infinite intervals do so explicitly, rather than just using a large number as the endpoint. This increases the chance of a correct answer – any function whose integral over an infinite interval is finite must be near zero for most of that interval.

(The rest of the *Note* is worth reading as well.)

If I change your upper limit of 10000000 to Inf I get a sensible-looking result. (But note that this sort of problem can *never* be completely solved in general ... sometimes you need to tune intervals, starting number of points, etc., to your particular problem.)

Core of your code with Inf substituted, rewritten slightly for clarity:

```
f1 <- function(x) tau*(x-v_p-interest*d_p[i])*
        dlnorm(x, log(v_p)+(mu - 0.5 * sigma_p^2) * time_t, sigma_p*sqrt(time_t))
f2 <- function(y) nu_p * y *
      dlnorm(y, log(v_p)+(mu - 0.5 * sigma_p^2) * time_t, sigma_p*sqrt(time_t))
for (i in 1:length(d_p)){
  ts  = c(ts,integrate(f1, v_p+interest*d_p[i], Inf)$value)
  bc = c(bc,integrate(f2, 0, d_p[i])$value)
}
```

(By the way, you should also avoid growing objects in R; allocate your entire vectors first rather than repeatedly appending to them.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Looping over 1000+ settings, I have found 5 cases where this error occurs. Using `adaptIntegrate()` solved the problem, probably because it uses another type of quadrature. Good example for the use of graphics to check results, I guess..